# What to do with the many duplicate/similar "No WiFi after upgrade" questions?

Tags: support, duplicates

I've seen several of these lately, and one of the latest one had the side-bar filled with them, none of them with marked answers, as you can see here:

[image: screenshot]

Here are the links:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/400186/updated-to-ubuntu-12-10-now-cannot-connect-to-internet
- [Cannot connect wireless internet with 12.10 on Dell Inspiron 1525](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216407/cannot-connect-wireless-internet-with-12-10-on-dell-inspiron-1525?rq=1) - Actually answered by 5 answers, though none marked.
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/270429/internet-connection-issue-ubuntu-12-10?rq=1 - Commented on, but no OP response
- [Ubuntu 12.10 : wireless not working after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253446/ubuntu-12-10-wireless-not-working-after-update?rq=1) - Has an answer, but not marked
- [I have issues connecting to Internet in Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261210/i-have-issues-connecting-to-internet-in-ubuntu-12-10?rq=1) - Again, answered, but not marked.
- [How can I fix my WiFi on Ubuntu 12.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266495/how-can-i-fix-my-wifi-on-ubuntu-12-10?rq=1) - Double, answer. Again, unmarked
- [Cant Connect to Internet with Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279458/cant-connect-to-internet-with-ubuntu-12-10?rq=1) - Again, commented on, but no OP response
- [Cant Connect to Internet with Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279458/cant-connect-to-internet-with-ubuntu-12-10?rq=1) - Answered, but not marked.

These are all slightly different, but still similar. There has to be some dupes there, but I have no clue which ones to mark!

Thanks!

Comment: Yet another: http://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/204857

Answer (score 1):

Answer them. If a answer is not possible, close them. Comment them to get OP input if it's not clear, but never duplicate them against questions that will not help.

If accepted/upvoted answers is given, then ask those answerers to make a new question about the models/chips their answers works against, to make them searchable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Wifi problems are common not just to Ubuntu, but other Linux OS's as well, including of course Ubuntu derivatives. Perhaps there should be a sticky/section dedicated to Wifi problems? Have it mentioned that when you post your problem, to put in make, model, and what wireless internet chip they are using.